# SEO - multiple page with same keywords but different content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have a this website

http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/

which is on web development tutorials.

My Question is Can I have multiple page with same keywords but different content for eg.

Here is a page that is tutorial on if/else condition in php

http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/php-tutorials/if-else-condition/

I want to create few pages like this

```
http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/php-exercise/if-else-condition/
http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/javascript-exercise/if-else-condition/
http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/php/if-else-condition/
```

All these pages will have different content which are needed and make sense

I am using the SEO Yoast plugin in wordpress which said you are using a duplicate keyword.

I want to know if Google will understand that these are different pages with different context/content and are needed by users or will it penalize me for using duplicate keywords in page titles and url's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this would not be an issue. Google looks at your url, meta title and the content of your pages to understand what they are all about. If the content is sufficiently different between them, but they do share a couple of keywords, it is not going to be an issue at all. No worries.

At most, if the content is not specific at all, they might be considered near duplicate content, but you are not going to be penalized for that. At worst, such pages would not rank well.

Comment: Thanks. I would go ahead and write the content for the users. 
Users come first. I am sure google is intelligent enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose the keywords your pages are relevant for. They are or are not relevant for keywords based on many factors, some of which, but not all of them, are the titles and URLs of the pages. You do get to choose the topics the content is about, though.

Additionally, it is common for pages to have a lot of keywords and content in common. What matters is that they are not *the same* content. Writing a tutorial about if/else statements in PHP is different than writing one for Java.

The only way you may run into issues is if you copy the content from the PHP article to the Java article and than do a blanket search and replace of PHP with Java. That's low quality content and bad for SEO. But if you take the time to write custom content for both this is fine for SEO and your users.

Comment: Thanks John,

My explanation about if-else condition would be a page like this